# 3971 The server failed to resume the transaction

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

We are using `.net2.0` windows service which will check the service broker queue depth and will do same operation. Its running in miultiple thread. We are getting below error in prod. Not our test environment.

```
Details:  Error Numer:3971 The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:8600000131. on line:1Error reported by.Net SqlClient Data Provider while connected to XXXXXX server
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty sparse on details, especially with regards to the code that will need to be fixed to address this issue.

If you do a Google search on that exact error message you end up with a pretty good idea of what causes it.  In short, your .net code is attempting to continue statements on a **transaction id** after it has been `committed` or `rolled back`.

You need to identify the cause of this in your code.  It can be for a variety of reasons but one of the more common is not using classes that implement `iDisposable` or failing to use `Using` statements.

You also mention multi-threading which introduces all kinds of opportunities for this error to pop up.  One thread completing a transaction while another is trying to work against it, etc.